# Function pointer reference parameter conversion to const

Tags: c++

The sample code:

```
class Foo;
typedef void (*fnptr)(Foo &foo);
fnptr gFn;
void myfoo(const Foo &foo) {}

int main() {
    gFn = &myfoo;
}
```

Fails with the following error using clang:

```
main.cpp:9:9: error: assigning to 'fnptr' (aka 'void (*)(Foo &)') from incompatible type
      'void (*)(const Foo &)': type mismatch at 1st parameter ('Foo &' vs 'const Foo &')
    gFn = &myfoo;
        ^ ~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

GCC also fails with a similar error. Passing a pointer instead of a reference also

I don't really understand why this is an error. A function accepting a const Foo& also accept a Foo& as argument and, in both cases, a pointer is passed down. I would like to understand why this is an error.

Comment: compiler message is pretty straightforward...

Comment: A function of the signature `void(*)(const Foo&)` is **not** the same as `void(*)(Foo&)`. Remember that you can overload a function solely on *cv* qualifications. Your function pointer `fnptr` says its function pointer type that will only point to functions to that takes a non-const `Foo&` and return `void`. For example, you can pass `rvalues` to `const Foo&`, but you can't to for the `Foo&`. These constraints must be checked too on the function pointer.

Comment: A function accepting const Foo& DOES accept Foo& as argument, but saying that "a method that takes a const Foo& has the same signature as a method that accepts Foo&" is wrong (hence the compiler yelling at you)

Comment: This is akin to saying `void (*f)(char)` should be able to point to `void (int)`, which is not the case. That there are implicit conversions between types does not mean they are the same

Comment: even your argumentation about taking the same arguments was valid, not every parameter that you can pass to a `void foo(const T&)` can be passed to a `void foo(T&)`

Comment: What you also need to ask yourself is; `typedef void(*fnptr)(Foo *foo);` will work with `void myfoo(Foo *const foo)`, but not with `void myfoo(const Foo *foo)`

Answer (score 2):

A function of the signature `void(*)(const Foo&)` is **not** the same as `void(*)(Foo&)`.

For example, you can pass `rvalues` to `void myfoo(const Foo&)`, but you can't to for the `void myfoo(Foo&)`. As, you know, such constraint on what you can pass are checked at compile-time for functions at the call site.

For the sake of sanity, those constraint are also checked on function pointers.

Example:

```
class Foo{};

using FooPtr = void(*)(Foo&);
using ConstFooPtr = void(*)(const Foo&);

void fooNonConst(Foo&) { }
void fooConst(const Foo&) { }


int main() {
    FooPtr ptr1 = &fooNonConst;
    ConstFooPtr ptr2 = &fooConst;

    ptr1(Foo{});   //Not OK
    ptr2(Foo{});   //Ok
}
```

Comment: Which justify why you can't convert from "void myfoo(Foo&)" to "void myfoo(const Foo&)" but the question is about the other way around.

Comment: afaik even if `void Foo(T)` and `void Bar(U)` can be passed the same types taking into account possible conversions, pointers to them cannot be "converted" unless `U==T`

Comment: @deadalnix, its the same reason. Think about it. Why should a function pointer, who promises to only point to `void(*)(const Foo&)` ("I promise not to modify the argument") later bind to a function `void(*)(Foo&)` that could modify the argument?

Comment: @WhiZTiM Still thinking about it the wrong way around. We promise to point to a ````void(*)(Foo&)```` ("I may modify - but do not have to") and later bind to a ````void(*)(const Foo&)```` ("I won't modify, which is a subset of I may modify")

Comment: @deadalnix, Ok. Please clarify... possibly with a code example

Comment: @WhiZTiM The code example is as above. You keep justifying that one cannot convert ````void(*)(Foo&)```` into a ````void(*)(const Foo&)```` . This is NOT the question. The question is why one cannot convert ````void(*)(const Foo&)```` into ````void(*)(Foo&)```` .

Comment: @deadalnix, *"The question is why one cannot convert `void(*)(const Foo&)` into `void(*)(Foo&)`"* - because a function of `void(*)(Foo&)` can modify its argument! While `void(*)(const Foo&)` doesn't... You break that invariant, and the world will literally  break

Comment: ````void(*)(Foo&)```` CAN modify its argument. This is why you can't convert ````void(*)(Foo&)```` to ````void(*)(const Foo&)```` . We are interested in the reverse case here.

Comment: @deadalnix, *"("I won't modify, which is a subset of I may modify")"* - This is where you are missing it.`void(*)(Foo&)` is **not** a subset of `void(*)(const Foo&)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145565/discussion-between-whiztim-and-deadalnix).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simply *because the standard mandates it*. Why do we drive on the right in US and on the left in UK? Ok kind of joking, but not that much. There are quite a lot of corner cases like that, where we find ourselves thinking but why didn't they allow this or that? And sometimes what was disallowed in a version of the standard become allowed in a next one. For example in C++98, only static const integral members could be initialized in a class declaration, all other members should be initialized in a constructor. C++11 allows initialization of members in a class declaration.

But here what you ask for would probably make type safety controls harder for compilers, while they are already quite complex!

So the way to go here for a conformant program in to use a wrapper around `myfoo`:

```
void myfoo_wrap(Foo &foo) {
    myfoo(foo);
}
```

I must admit that this may look stupid, but the good news is that an optimizing compiler should be able to remove it from the executable. That means that is is lite in source and not noticiable in executable: I'm afraid that this rule will not be changed soon in standard...

Comment: as a solution would be `std::function<void(Foo &foo)>` instead of wrapper. std::function makes the conversion